# Tobit regression in R: Warning : "replacing response values greater than the value 1 by 1"

Tags: r, regression

I am running a `vglm tobit` regression with package VGMA.

```
Shit = vglm( y ~ x, data=M,  tobit(Lower=0, Upper=1))
```

Now R gives me:

```
"In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  replacing response values greater than the value 1 by 1"
```

...and i have no Idea what to do?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: ...problem solved, Thanks! (max value was 1 :-) )

Comment: Can you tell what was the problem and how it was solved?

Comment: I am a little bit ashamed. Max Value was 1, but there has been a hidden "inf" value in my dataframe